# MSI, UAC and Unidentified Publisher. How do I change the Unidentified Publisher?

Tags: c#, windows-installer, certificate, uac

I am currently working on a MSI package for one of my application. It works well; however, before the installation starts, I get the expected UAC window asking me if I trust or not this program from the *Unidentified Publisher*. **I am not concerned by UAC itself, but by the *Unidentified Publisher*. How do I change that?** I've heard that I need a special certificate... If it is the case, where can I get it?

[image]
<sub>(source: [backuphowto.info](http://www.backuphowto.info/files/images/review/2008/04/shadowexplorer/shadowexplorer-1.png))</sub>

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a pretty good reference to it...

[John Robbin's Code Signing Article](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2007/12/21/code-signing-it-s-cheaper-and-easier-than-you-thought.aspx)

Answer (score 9):

You need a ***code signing certificate.***

I use and recommend [Comodo](http://www.comodo.com/) which charge as [little as $179/year](http://www.instantssl.com/code-signing/). This is a real bargain when compared to [$499/year from Verisign](http://www.verisign.com/products-services/security-services/code-signing/digital-ids-code-signing/index.html)